# How is a template function evaluated by a compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

Consider the following variadic template function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto foo(Args... args) -> T[sizeof...(args)]
{
   T t[sizeof...(args)];
   // Maybe do some pack expansion/assignment
   return t;
}
```

with the instantiation:

```
// total should be of type int[5];
auto total = foo(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I understand that this will not compile, due to the return type not being deducible, but I do not understand *why* it is not deducible.

Is there something about this function that the compiler does/can not know at compile time, or the order of parts of the function being evaluated, which prevents type deduction?

I suspect it is due to the calling of the function `sizeof...`, which I think evaluates at run-time. If so, is there a compile-time equivalent?

Comment: Which standard are you targetting? (Forgive me if that's ignorant.)

Comment: At the moment, C++11

Comment: Hum. This part of C++ is moving quite quickly and I ain't no expert in any of it. C++14 might compile this you know.

Comment: Unfortunately C++14 currently isn't an option. Not my decision to make.

Comment: @Bathsheba C++17 doesn't even compile it :)

Comment: You should not return a local non static array from a function.

Comment: Indeed. I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Well I may as well stick to ANSI C then :-)

Comment: `T` can't be deduced from argument list at the call point! Only `Args` template args are used in the parameter list.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot return built-in arrays by value. Use `std::array` instead.

Also, as it stands, you'll need to explicitly provide the type `T` as a template argument as it does not appear in the argument list. Thus the compiler has nothing to deduce it from.

Complete example:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto foo(Args... args) -> std::array<T, sizeof...(args)>
{
   std::array<T, sizeof...(args)> t;
   // Maybe do some pack expansion/assignment
   return t;
}

int main () {
    auto a = foo<int>(1,2,3);
}
```

Depending on the usecase, you may get rid of the explicit template argument by e.g. using the `std::common_type` of all elements in the pack or `static_assert`ing they all have the same type and use that.

Also, for the record, `sizeof...` does yield a compile-time constant. The problem is, to make the answer explicit, that the compiler has no way tell what `T` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 7):

Compiler unable to deduce T, because you don't pass T to function argument.

```
auto total = foo<int>(1,2,3,4,5);
```

If we correctly put T manually as template argument - it will [compile & work fine on G++7.1](https://godbolt.org/g/uHcU5u)

Or, you can simply `decltype` required type from variadic argument.

something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename...Args>
T getHead(T&& arg, Args&&...) {
     return arg;
}


template<typename... Args>
auto foo(Args... args)
{
     using TYPE = typename std::decay<decltype(getHead(args...))>::type;
     return std::array<TYPE, sizeof...(Args)>{ args... };
}
```

And yes, use std::array, return local C-style array is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are quite correct, but my example is flawed. I will ask a new question so as to not confuse the answers.

Comment: @IanYoung I've probably just answered yours in edit :)

Comment: "it will compile & work fine on G++7.1" - could you please add a reference to godbolt.org?

Comment: @Starl1ght ehm, I was mostly interested how you compiled the OP's example :)

Comment: @Starl1ght It would be better to use `std::common_type` instead of the type of the first argument.